# Google API key error if I am on localhost

Tags: javascript, api, maps

I have a map in a web page PHP/HTML.

```
<script type="text/javascript" async defer src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"></script>
```

If the page is in an online server, all work great.
If I test it on localhost with WAMP, no map are loaded and I get always this error on my firefox console:

```
TypeError: can't convert a to string: its [Symbol.toPrimitive] method returned an object js:26:120
    Ba http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:26
    <anonima> http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:154
    Ea http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:27
    <anonima> http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:152
    <anonima> http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:225
```

My API has no restriction, so i don't know why this problem.

Comment: what if you set `https:` as the protocol in the source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Was a compatibility issue with plugin jquery multiple-select 1.4.1.

Solved with 1.4.0 version.